# Question on Rudin theorem 8.7

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Here is the  theorem:

(1) The function $E$ is periodic, with period $2\pi i$.

(2) The functions $C$ and $S$ are periodic, with period $2\pi$.

(3) If $0 < t < 2\pi$, then $E(it) \neq 1$.

(4) If $z$ is a complex number with $|z|= 1$, there is a unique $t$ in $[0, 2\pi)$ such that $E(it) = z$.

$$E(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {z^n}{n!},$$
$$C(x) = \frac {E(ix)+E(-ix)}{2},\; S(x) = \frac {E(ix)-E(-ix)}{2i}.$$

My question is about the proof of the theorem's 4th part.
Uniqueness is understandable.
Here is the proof by rudin:
To prove the existence assertion in (4), fix $z$ so that $|z|=1$. Write $z = x+iy$, with $x$ and $y$ real. Suppose first that
$x\ge 0$  and $y \ge 0$. On $[0,\pi/2]$, $C$ decreases from $1$ to $0$.

Hence $C(t) = x$ for some $t\in [0,\pi/2]$.

Since $C^2 + S^2 = 1$ and  $S \ge 0$  on $[0,\pi/2]$ it follows that $z = E(it)$.

If $x < 0$ and $y \ge 0 $, the preceding conditions are satisfied by $-iz$. Hence $-iz = E(it)$ for some $t\in [0,\pi/2]$, and since $i = E(\pi i/2)$, we obtain $z = E(i(t+\pi/2))$.

Finally, if $y < 0$, the preceding two cases show that $- z = E(it)$ for some $t\in$ $(0,\pi)$. Hence $z = -E(it) = E(i(t+\pi))$. This proves (4).

I don't understand why the $C(t) = x$ for some $t \in [0,\pi/2]$.

I also don't understand why the preceding conditions are satisfied by $ -iz = E(it)$ in the second case and hence I don't understand why $-z = E(it)$ in the third case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are $E$, $C$ ans $S$? is the power series in your OP is to be taken as definition of $E$? and $C$ and $S$ defined by the expressions right below the power series? If so, please make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since $C\left(\frac\pi2\right)=0\leqslant x\leqslant1=C(0)$ and $C$ is continuous, it follows from the intermediate value theorem that there is some $t\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$ such that $C(t)=x$.

And if $z=x+yi$ with $x<0$ and $y\geqslant0$, then $-iz=y-xi$. But then, since $y\geqslant0$, there is some $t\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$ such that $E(it)=-iz$.

Comment: I still don't get it. why does the fact that y $\ge$ 0 changes something?

Comment: Because then the real part of $-iz$ is greater than or equal to $0$, and then you in the first case. And so you already know that $E(it)=-iz$ for some $t\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$.